# Async streaming of Reddit posts

Tags: rust, asynchronous

[`roux`](https://docs.rs/roux/1.3.5/roux/) is a Rust library that wraps the Reddit API. Neither Reddit nor `roux` provides a stream-like interface for obtaining the latest submissions automatically, so that's what I've implemented here.

I'm learning Rust as a hobby (I'm a Python developer by trade) and this is my first "serious" Rust project. Please feel free to point out anything that sticks out to you. The following points are particularly interesting to me:

- Am I using references and owned values appropriately (e.g. no unnecessary cloning)?
- Is the interface provided by my `lib.rs` fitting for this use case (async streaming of items) and idiomatic?
- As a Rust newbie, the types in the `where` declarations are hard to understand. Would it be useful to introduce some aliases?
- Is my approach to error handling OK?

`lib.rs`:

```rust
#![warn(missing_docs)]

/*!
Streaming API for `roux`

Reddit's API does not provide "firehose"-style streaming of new posts and
comments. Instead, the endpoint for retrieving the latest posts has to be
polled regularly. This crate automates that task and provides a stream
for a subreddit's posts (submissions).

See [`stream_subreddit_submissions`] for details.

# Logging

This module uses the logging infrastructure provided by the [`log`] crate.
*/

use futures::{Sink, SinkExt};
use log::{debug, warn};
use roux::subreddit::responses::SubmissionsData;
use roux::{util::RouxError, Subreddit};
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::marker::Unpin;
use tokio::time::{sleep, Duration};
use tokio_retry::Retry;

/// Error that may happen when streaming submissions
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum SubmissionStreamError<S>
where
    S: Sink<SubmissionsData> + Unpin,
{
    /// An issue with getting the data from Reddit
    Roux(RouxError),

    /// An issue with sending the data through the sink
    Sink(S::Error),
}

/**
Stream new submissions in a subreddit

The subreddit is polled regularly for new submissions, and each previously
unseen submission is sent into the sink.

`sleep_time` controls the interval between calls to the Reddit API, and depends
on how much traffic the subreddit has. Each call fetches the 100 latest items
(the maximum number allowed by Reddit). A warning is logged if none of those
items has been seen in the previous call: this indicates a potential miss of new
content and suggests that a smaller `sleep_time` should be chosen.

`retry_strategy` controls how to deal with errors that occur while fetching
content from Reddit. See [`tokio_retry::strategy`].
*/
pub async fn stream_subreddit_submissions<S, R, I>(
    subreddit: &Subreddit,
    mut sink: S,
    sleep_time: Duration,
    retry_strategy: &R,
) -> Result<(), SubmissionStreamError<S>>
where
    S: Sink<SubmissionsData> + Unpin,
    R: IntoIterator<IntoIter = I, Item = Duration> + Clone,
    I: Iterator<Item = Duration>,
{
    // How many submissions to fetch per request
    const LIMIT: u32 = 100;
    let mut seen_ids: HashSet<String> = HashSet::new();

    loop {
        let latest_submissions =
            Retry::spawn(retry_strategy.clone(), || subreddit.latest(LIMIT, None))
                .await
                .map_err(SubmissionStreamError::Roux)?
                .data
                .children
                .into_iter()
                .map(|thing| thing.data);

        let mut latest_ids: HashSet<String> = HashSet::new();

        let mut num_new = 0;
        for submission in latest_submissions {
            latest_ids.insert(submission.id.clone());
            if !seen_ids.contains(&submission.id) {
                num_new += 1;
                sink.send(submission)
                    .await
                    .map_err(SubmissionStreamError::Sink)?
            }
        }

        debug!(
            "Got {} new submissions for r/{} (out of {})",
            num_new, subreddit.name, LIMIT
        );
        if num_new == LIMIT && !seen_ids.is_empty() {
            warn!(
                "All received submissions for r/{} were new, try a shorter sleep_time",
                subreddit.name
            );
        }

        seen_ids = latest_ids;
        sleep(sleep_time).await;
    }
}
```

`main.rs`:

```rust
use futures::{channel::mpsc, Stream, StreamExt};
use roux::{subreddit::responses::SubmissionsData, Subreddit};
use tokio;
use tokio::time::Duration;
use tokio_retry::strategy::{jitter, ExponentialBackoff};

use subreddit_dumper;

async fn submission_reader<S>(stream: &mut S)
where
    S: Stream<Item = SubmissionsData> + Unpin,
{
    while let Some(submission) = stream.next().await {
        println!(
            "New submission in r/{} by {}",
            submission.subreddit, submission.author
        );
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // Initialize logging
    stderrlog::new()
        .module(module_path!())
        .verbosity(3)
        .init()
        .unwrap();

    let subreddit = Subreddit::new("AskReddit");

    let (mut submission_sender, mut submission_receiver) = mpsc::unbounded();

    let retry_strategy = ExponentialBackoff::from_millis(100)
        .map(jitter) // add jitter to delays
        .take(3); // limit to 3 retries

    let (submission_res, _) = tokio::join!(
        subreddit_dumper::stream_subreddit_submissions(
            &subreddit,
            &mut submission_sender,
            Duration::from_secs(60),
            &retry_strategy,
        ),
        submission_reader(&mut submission_receiver),
    );
    submission_res.unwrap();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is good for the most parts, however there are some improvements that can be made:

The final line in your `main` method `submission_res.unwrap()` should be changed to handle the errors and maybe log them.

---

Personally, I would change the structure of the library. Instead of calling the `async` method `stream_subreddit_submissions` with all the different configuration parameters, I would create a struct called `SubmissionsStream` that has two methods:

```rust
pub fn new(
        subreddit: Subreddit,
        sink: S,
        sleep_time: Duration,
        retry_strategy: R,
    ) -> SubmissionsStream
```

For creating the `SumbissionsStream` with all the configuration.

```rust
pub async fn run(self) -> Result<(), SubmissionStreamError<S::Error>>
```

For running the stream.

I would also suggest to pull as much of the configuration creation inside of the `new()` method. For example you can change `new()` to create the `mpsc` channel inside and return the receiver, rather than passing the sender to it. However this would limit you from using a specific `mpsc` channel so I would leave it only as a suggestion and not something that you necessarily have to do.

---

`SubmissionStreamError` should implement the standard traits `Display` and `Error`.

---

The logic for the seen ids can be optimised.

When you are checking if an id has been seen or not in the `for` loop, and you find an id that has been seen, you can break from the loop because you would have seen all of the ids after it (iff `roux` returns the latest posts ordered by time, which seems to be the case from testing it).

This means that you don't need to have two `HashSet`s and this:

```rust
let mut latest_ids: HashSet<String> = HashSet::new();

let mut num_new = 0;
for submission in latest_submissions {
    latest_ids.insert(submission.id.clone());
    if !seen_ids.contains(&submission.id) {
        num_new += 1;
        sink.send(submission)
            .await
            .map_err(SubmissionStreamError::Sink)?
    }
}
```

can be simplified:

```rust
let mut num_new = 0;

for submission in latest_submissions {
    if !seen_ids.contains(&submission.id) {
        seen_ids.insert(submission.id.clone());
        num_new += 1;
        sink.send(submission)
            .await
            .map_err(SubmissionStreamError::Sink)?
    } else {
        //If you reach a seen submission you
        // will have seen all other submissions after it.
        break;
    }
}
```

---

**Final Code:**

`lib.rs`

```rust
use futures::{Sink, SinkExt};
use log::{debug, warn};
use roux::subreddit::responses::SubmissionsData;
use roux::{util::RouxError, Subreddit};
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::error::Error;
use std::fmt::{Debug, Display, Formatter};
use std::marker::Unpin;
use tokio::time::{sleep, Duration};
use tokio_retry::Retry;

/// Error that may happen when streaming submissions
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum SubmissionStreamError<SinkErr> {
    /// An issue with getting the data from Reddit
    Roux(RouxError),
    /// An issue with sending the data through the sink
    Sink(SinkErr),
}

impl<S: Debug + Display> Display for SubmissionStreamError<S> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        match self {
            SubmissionStreamError::Roux(roux_err) => {
                write!(f, "{}", roux_err)
            }
            SubmissionStreamError::Sink(sink_err) => {
                write!(f, "{}", sink_err)
            }
        }
    }
}

impl<S: Debug + Display> Error for SubmissionStreamError<S> {}

pub struct SubmissionsStream<S, R> {
    subreddit: Subreddit,
    sink: S,
    sleep_time: Duration,
    retry_strategy: R,
}

impl<S, R, I> SubmissionsStream<S, R>
where
    S: Sink<SubmissionsData> + Unpin,
    R: IntoIterator<IntoIter = I, Item = Duration> + Clone,
    I: Iterator<Item = Duration>,
{
    pub fn new(
        subreddit: Subreddit,
        sink: S,
        sleep_time: Duration,
        retry_strategy: R,
    ) -> SubmissionsStream<S, R> {
        SubmissionsStream {
            subreddit,
            sink,
            sleep_time,
            retry_strategy,
        }
    }

    pub async fn run(self) -> Result<(), SubmissionStreamError<S::Error>> {
        let SubmissionsStream {
            subreddit,
            mut sink,
            sleep_time,
            retry_strategy,
        } = self;

        const LIMIT: u32 = 100;
        let mut seen_ids: HashSet<String> = HashSet::new();

        loop {
            let latest_submissions =
                Retry::spawn(retry_strategy.clone(), || subreddit.latest(LIMIT, None))
                    .await
                    .map_err(SubmissionStreamError::Roux)?
                    .data
                    .children
                    .into_iter()
                    .map(|thing| thing.data);

            let mut num_new = 0;

            for submission in latest_submissions {
                if !seen_ids.contains(&submission.id) {
                    seen_ids.insert(submission.id.clone());
                    num_new += 1;
                    sink.send(submission)
                        .await
                        .map_err(SubmissionStreamError::Sink)?
                } else {
                    //If you reach a seen submission you
                    // will have seen all other submissions after it.
                    break;
                }
            }

            debug!(
                "Got {} new submissions for r/{} (out of {})",
                num_new, subreddit.name, LIMIT
            );
            if num_new == LIMIT && !seen_ids.is_empty() {
                warn!(
                    "All received submissions for r/{} were new, try a shorter sleep_time",
                    subreddit.name
                );
            }

            sleep(sleep_time).await;
        }
    }
}
```

`main.rs`

```rust
use futures::{channel::mpsc, Stream, StreamExt};
use log::debug;
use roux::{subreddit::responses::SubmissionsData, Subreddit};
use tokio::time::Duration;
use tokio_retry::strategy::{jitter, ExponentialBackoff};

async fn submission_reader<S>(stream: &mut S)
where
    S: Stream<Item = SubmissionsData> + Unpin,
{
    while let Some(submission) = stream.next().await {
        println!(
            "New submission in r/{} by {}",
            submission.subreddit, submission.author
        );
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // Initialize logging
    stderrlog::new()
        .module(module_path!())
        .verbosity(3)
        .init()
        .unwrap();

    let subreddit = Subreddit::new("AskReddit");
    let (submission_sender, mut submission_receiver) = mpsc::unbounded();
    let retry_strategy = ExponentialBackoff::from_millis(100)
        .map(jitter) // add jitter to delays
        .take(3); // limit to 3 retries

    let submission_stream = subreddit_dumper::SubmissionsStream::new(
        subreddit,
        submission_sender,
        Duration::from_secs(60),
        retry_strategy,
    );

    let (submission_res, _) = tokio::join!(
        submission_stream.run(),
        submission_reader(&mut submission_receiver),
    );

    if let Err(stream_err) = submission_res {
        debug!("Error:  {}", stream_err);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! One thing regarding your suggested improvement of checking for seen IDs: in your version, `seen_ids` seems to grow indefinitely. That's something I'd like to avoid, since one intended use case are long-running Reddit bots. I do like the idea of wrapping the functionality in a struct!